# Nginx Config File in every server block

Tags: nginx

I a setting up an nginx server with php-fpm and was wondering how to include a file with every new server I create?
E.G:
this code is in a file called 'server_config.conf' in /etc/nginx:

```
location = /favicon.ico
{
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt
{
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
```

Every server (vhost) needs to include this block and I am doing it like this:

```
#domain-one.com
server
{
    include  /etc/nginx/server_config.conf;

    server_name  domain-one.com www.domain-one.com;
    root  /var/www/vhosts/domain-one.com/httpdocs;

    access_log  /var/www/vhosts/domain-one.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log  /var/www/vhosts/domain-one.com/logs/error.log;
}

# domain-two.com
server
{
    include  /etc/nginx/server_config.conf;

    ......
}
```

Is it possible to get the "/etc/nginx/server_config.conf" file included with every server block automatically without having to put "include  /etc/nginx/server_config.conf;" in every server block manually?

Thanks

Comment: This should probably be asked on ServerFault

Comment: hi, have you ever found answer for this question?